# Add Enterprise Keywords to a library programatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, modern-experience, enterprise-keywords

When we go to the settings of a library, we can navigate to
**Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings**

In here there is a checkbox that can be activated.
If activated through the UI, the checkbox stays enabled on further openings of this setting.

If we try to add the Enterprise Keywords field to the list, it doesn't seem to perform the same actions as if we pressed the checkbox in the UI.

There is an old post with this same problem,

[Programmatically enable Enterprise Keywords for a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9486/programmatically-enable-enterprise-keywords-for-a-list)

Has anyone found how to enable Enterprise Keywords programatically in such a way that the setting will also become enabled when navigating to the option in the UI?

[image]
on the left: setting enabled through the UI

on the right: column added to the list programatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the solution is, in short, to **add the field at the list content type** level.

Here are some details:

- if we query List.ContentTypes we will probably get a number of content types, including "Folder". Folder does not need Enterprise Keywords
- the checkbox will be automatically enabled or disabled, depending on whether ALL DOCUMENT CONTENT TYPES have the Enterprise Keywords field associated with them. so if we add a new content type to the library, the checkbox will be unchecked again
- we can enable the checkbox "manually" using the UI, by basically going to each of the list's document content types and adding the Enterprise Keywords there
- we might need to make the list content type read-only flag set to "No"/False in order to make changes (programatically or through the UI)
- now that we know all this, we can perform the same actions, but programatically

below is an example code to perform this

```
public void AddEnterpriseKeywords(ClientContext context, string libraryTitle)
        {
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryTitle);
            FieldCollection fields = list.Fields;
            ContentTypeCollection cts = list.ContentTypes;
            context.Load(fields);
            context.Load(cts, ct => ct.Include(x => x.Fields, x => x.Fields.Include(y => y.Title), x => x.Name, x => x.StringId, x => x.ReadOnly));
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            Field webEntKeywords = context.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Enterprise Keywords");

            //add Enterprise Keywords to the list
            if (fields.Where(x => x.Title == "Enterprise Keywords").FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adding field: Enterprise Keywords...");
                list.Fields.Add(webEntKeywords);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Field added.");

                context.Load(list.Fields);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }

            //add Enterprise Keywords field to all Document content types
            foreach(ContentType ct in cts.Where(x => x.StringId.StartsWith("0x0101")))
            {
                if (ct.Fields.Where(x => x.Title == "Enterprise Keywords").FirstOrDefault() == null)
                {
                    bool readOnlyFlag = false;
                    if(ct.ReadOnly)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Making content type writable...");
                        ct.ReadOnly = false;
                        ct.Update(false);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                        readOnlyFlag = true;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Associating Enterprise Keywords with content type: " + ct.Name);
                    FieldLinkCreationInformation newField = new FieldLinkCreationInformation();
                    newField.Field = list.Fields.Where(x => x.Title == "Enterprise Keywords").FirstOrDefault();
                    ct.FieldLinks.Add(newField);
                    ct.Update(false);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                    if(readOnlyFlag)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Making content type read-only...");
                        ct.ReadOnly = true;
                        ct.Update(false);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
}
```